# Safely merge data frames by factor columns

Tags: r, merge

Factors can help preventing some kinds of programming errors in R: You cannot perform equality check for factors that use different levels, and you are warned when performing greater/less than checks for unordered factors.

```
a <- factor(letters[1:3])
b <- factor(letters[1:3], levels=letters[4:1])
a == b
## Error in Ops.factor(a, b) : level sets of factors are different
a < a
## [1] NA NA NA
## Warning message:
## In Ops.factor(a, a) : < not meaningful for factors
```

However, contrary to my expectation, this check is not performed when merging data frames:

```
ad <- data.frame(x=a, a=as.numeric(a))
bd <- data.frame(x=b, b=as.numeric(b))
merge(ad, bd)
##   x a b
## 1 a 1 4
## 2 b 2 3
## 3 c 3 2
```

Those factors simply seem to be coerced to characters.

Is a "safe merge" available somewhere that would do the check? Do you see specific reasons for not doing this check by default?

**Example** (real-life use case): Assume two spatial data sets with very similar but not identical subdivision in, say, communes. The data sets refer to slightly different points in time, and some of the communes have merged during that time span. Each data set has a "commune ID" column, perhaps even named identically. While the semantics of this column are very similar, I wouldn't want to (accidentally) merge the data sets over this commune ID column. Instead, I construct a matching table between "old" and "new" commune IDs. If the commune IDs are encoded as factors, a "safe merge" would give a correctness check for the merge operation at no extra (implementation) cost and very little computational cost.

Comment: IIUC, you'd prefer an error in this case because the levels don't match?

Comment: @Arun: In many use cases I would prefer an error, or at the very least a warning.

Comment: I see. Out of curiosity, in what way do you consider this unsafe?

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm guessing you're looking for a "cleaner" solution than adding an if-statement to check for the levels.. (on by-columns)?

Answer (score 2):

The "safe guard" with `merge` is the `by=` parameter. You can set exactly which columns you think should match. If you match up two factor columns, R will use the the labels for those values to match them up. So "a" will match with "a" regardless of how the hidden inner working of factor have coded those values. That's what a user sees, so that's how it will be merged. It's just like with numeric values, you can choose to merge on columns that have complete different ranges (the first column has 1:10, the second has 100:1000). When the `by` value is set, R will do what it's asked. And if you don't explicitly set the `by` parameter, then R will find all shared column names in the two data.frames and use that.

And many times when merging, you don't always expect matches. Sometimes you're using `all.x` or `all.y` to specifically get unmatched records. In this case, depending on how the different data.frames were created, one may not know about the levels it doesn't have. So it's not at all unreasonable to to try to merge them.

So basically R is treating factors like characters during merging, be cause it assumes that you already know that two columns belong together.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with much credit (and apologies to) MrFlick:

```
> attributes(ad$x)
$levels
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$class
[1] "factor"


> attributes(ad$a)
NULL

> attributes(ad$b)
NULL

> adfoo<-merge(ad,bd)

> attributes(adfoo$x)
$levels
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$class
[1] "factor"
```

So in fact  the merged column `$x` is a factor, although only levels common to both `ad` and `bd` are merged.   The other columns  were coerced via as.numeric long ago.

Comment: I don't see where `data.frame` is removing the `factor` attribute from the initial values. What is the evidence of that?

Comment: @MrFlick  try running `attributes(a)` and `attributes(ad)` .  Please don't dump on posts without investigating first.

Comment: I wasn't dumping; I did investigate first which is why I was confused. I had compared `attributes(a)` and `attributes(ad$x)` which were identical. I was surprised to see you looking at `attributes(ad)`. A `data.frame` is just a collection of vectors. The `data.frame` itself doesn't take on the attributes of any one of its columns nor does attributes() recursively investigate the sub-elements. A `data.frame` can hold factors with different levels: `dd<-data.frame(x=letters[1:2], y=letters[11:12]);levels(dd$x); levels(dd$y)`

Comment: @MrFlick  My apologies -- hoist by my own petard.  I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't have expected that. So, the behavior is to create a new factor that contains the levels found in both data frames (modulo `all.x` or `all.y`). Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be documented (a coarse search in [the docs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/merge.html) for `factor` yields zero hits), but that's just another minor issue. The original question remains: Why??? (And is there an alternative that will do more strict checking?)